# XServer not working

Tags: centos, yum, x-server

After I remove the perl.i386 using yum remove, Centos 5.4 upon boot cannot start the XServer. How can I configure XServer to get it working? How can I add the other remove packages?

Answer (score 1):

You have to put perl back. Perl is critical to quite a few bits of CentOS. You may have broken your system to the point where only a reinstall will truly fix it, but your first step is to put perl back.

Comment: I have re-installed perl using rpm. But what about the issue with XServer. By doing yum reinstall perl.i386 will work?